# is this definition of meromorphic function missing a requirement?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Looking at Definition 1.1.33 in the book *Complex geometry* by Huybrechts:

**Def.** Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be open. A *meromorphic* function $f$ on $U$ is a function on the complement of a nowhere dense subset $S \subset U$ with the following property: there exist an open cover $U=\cup_i U_i$ and holomorphic functions $g_i,h_i:U_i\to\mathbb C$ with $h_i|_{U_i\setminus S}\cdot f|_{U_i\setminus S}=g_i|_{U_i\setminus S}$.

Isn't there a requirement on $h$ missing, i.e. $h_i \neq 0$ on $U_i\setminus S$?

Comment: Not quite that strong, but $h_i$ must not vanish identically on any component of $U_i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, so even if $S$ denotes the set of poles, $h_i$ can vanish outside $S$?

Comment: Yes, if the zeros of $h_i$ outside $S$ are cancelled by zeros of $g_i$. If you require $g_i$ and $h_i$ coprime (but that's some nasty algebra), then $h_i$ vanishes only on $S$.